# Lifecycle and validity of UIControl.frame properties

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

This is bugging me quit a bit. It seems like there is no predictable pattern for knowing when a control's frame properties are guaranteed to be valid. Specifically I'm trying to alter a UILabel's frame position depending on the hardware. In the both `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`, the frame property is nil. If I wait till `viewDidAppear` to adjust it, the user will see it the label move, which is crappy.

On other view controllers in the past I've been able to get label's frame in the eariler methods. What gives? Is there anything I can do to kick start the layout?

I should mention that the UILabel in question was added using IB and storyboards which is usually how I do my VCs.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try viewDidLayoutSubviews -- that's called before viewDidAppear. Alternately, you could adjust the position with constraints rather than frames, which you can do in viewDidLoad.